# Easymock , mocking with respect to particular method not done in android test cases

Tags: android, easymock

I noticed an unusual behavior with my android test cases that in a class there are two method methodA() and methodB() when i mocking the method methodA() than rather than mocking methodA() it is trying to mock methodB() and getting an exception trace. why is this behavior is attained? the trace was similar to given below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
CalledDAO.methodB({LastRequest=a.b.c.LastRequest@413d5ed8})
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()
at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:42)
at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
at $Proxy2.methodA(Native Method)
at a.b.c.SomeFragmentTest.testSimpleButtonClick1(SomeFragmentTest.java:501)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:545)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1574)
```

i am working with respect to methodA but why it is going to call methodB ???

Comment: Currently, it's quite difficult to say what's going on here. My best guess is that you're not providing the correct parameter values to get methodA called and as such, you're ending up with methodB being called instead. (Does methodB overload methodA?) To help us help you further, some indication of what methodA and methodB do would be helpful here. If you're mocking out those method calls, the you just need to provide the real method you're calling that calls methodA or B. The mock setup for the test code would also be very helpful.

Comment: @  Dan Temple Hi actually before this there was another method call was done by mocking object which i did not introduce so after introducing things were working, many thanks for reply!!